# Is it possible to upload files to S3 from browser in IE8?

Tags: file, upload, amazon-s3, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

Now I have this code in javascript.

```
var file_object = $('#PHOTO').get(0).files[0];

the_form = new FormData(); 
the_form.append("AWSAccessKeyId", "TESTING");
the_form.append("acl", "authenticated-read");
the_form.append("policy", policy);
the_form.append("signature", signature);
the_form.append("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
the_form.append("key", "test.jpg");
the_form.append("file", file_object);

$.ajax({
    url: "http://S3BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com",
    type: "POST",
    data: the_form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
})
```

It works sweetly, in Chrome, Firefox, except IE6,7,8,9.

The reason is that file object is not supported until IE10!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Is there any work-around solution for browsers before IE10?

PS: Code example would be nice!!

Answer (score 0):

Without Flash many things are definitely a no-go. I believe the lib you reference has some Flash fallbacks, but I'm unclear as to whether they can handle all the issues involved. This is something I'm currently dealing with myself, and here are the issues in brief:

- Content-Type header in response. IE (without Flash intermediary) will try to download a JSON content type, no way around this that I know without a proxy middleman to fudge headers.
- hostname mapping. If you *don't* map to origin hostname, IE iframe (which is the non-Flash fallback) will not allow you to read the contents of it from the containing window. Fire and forget may be possible, but consuming the response/detecting errors from s3 may not.

I will update this answer as I uncover more in the coming days. This is a large project so we have some pretty significant requirements and I imagine I'll learn a lot in the next week or so.

This is covered in a lot more detail here (not my company/project/post): http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/08/16/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser/